# unable to remove trailing space in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, space

I have a `DataFrame` and i have applied different functions to replace trailing space but there is no luck

```
df.select(col("e_no"),regexp_replace(col("e_no"),"//s+$",""),rtrim(col("e_no")),length(col("e_no"))).show()

e_no   | regexp_replace(e_no),//s+$, )| rtrim(e_no)|  length(e_no)
525071 |          525071 |              525071 |      7
512938|           512938|               512938|       6
522783 |          522783 |              522783 |      7
```

please could you advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rtrim function should work. As for the regex replace, the correct regular expression will be

> "\s+$"

Working code using spark: 2.2.1

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val list = Seq("525071 ", "512938", "522783 ")
val df = list.toDF("e_no")

df.select(
  col("e_no"),
  regexp_replace(col("e_no"), "\\s+$", ""),
  rtrim(col("e_no")),
  length(col("e_no"))
).show()
```

Comment: hi Tawkir
thanks for the reply! I tried neither trim nor the changed regex is working, this is a string column as well. I am not sure what's the problem :(

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: 2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235

Comment: Thanks the issue was there was a NUL character and not a space which was appearing like a space until i opened the file in sublime

Answer (score 1):

With `withColumn` method is the easiest way for my understanding:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val newDF = rawDF.withColumn("e_no", rtrim(col("e_no")))
 newDF.show()
```

Also you can use an UDF, but it may be overkilling the issue. Anyway is useful to get used to use UDFs, they are pretty helpful

```
val removeTrailingWhitespaces = (s:String) => {
  s.trim
}

val removeTrailingWhitespacesUdf = functions.udf(removeTrailingWhitespaces)

val newDF = rawDF
  .withColumn("e_no", removeTrailingWhitespacesUdf(rawDF("e_no")))

newDF.show()
```

I've run some tests for both options:

input:

```
H  ,173 
M,161
```

Output

```
+----+------+
|   H|   173|
|   M|   161|
+----+------+
```